# how to use jsp ForEach loop element in Scriptlets

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp

I want to assign ${element.cpReferralDtlsId} data variable.

```
<c:forEach items="${indentIssueData}" var="element">  
<tr>                          
<%
 String data =  ${element.cpReferralDtlsId};
%>
<td><%=++data %></td>   
</tr>
</c:forEach>`
```

Comment: When asking for help, it is good if you provide all information about what the problem is - eg. What error message (and on which line) are you seeing ????   I’m guessing you are facing a similar issue to this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/23601089/681444

Comment: How is `++data` meant to work with a variable of type `String`?

Comment: Also note that there is no Javascript in your snippet at all, so that tag seems to be superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

```
<c:forEach items="${indentIssueData}" var="element">  
<tr>                          
<%
 String data = element.getCpReferralDtlsId();
%>
<td><%=++data %></td>   
</tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Note that the ${} syntax is used in JSP expressions to evaluate and insert the result of a Java expression into the generated HTML. However, in this case, since we are already inside a scriptlet (<% %>) block, we don't need to use ${} to reference the element object. We can simply use the variable name directly.

Comment: Hi,Thank you for reply . I want to use  'data' variable value in some other logic.based on 'data' variable value i have written some other. Can you let me know how to get element.CpReferralDtlsId value in data varible .

Comment: <%
 String someOtherValue = "";
 if(data.equals("123")) {
   someOtherValue = "ABC";
 } else {
   someOtherValue = "DEF";
 }
%>